# Autolayouts Programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I need help in autolayouts. Am very new to Autolayouts and am not getting how to add auto layouts programmtically actually am getting below error.

When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2018-07-25 17:35:19.363248+0530

AutoLayoutsProgrammtically[4831:78876] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:UIButton:0x7f8e3ac0a6a0   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f8e3ad09cd0 )> view:>'

Below is the code :

```
 var button : UIButton = UIButton()
 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.view.addSubview(self.button)
// self.updateTheChanges()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
updateTheChanges()
}
func updateTheChanges() {
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.titleLabel?.text = "dasdasdas"
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
//left edge
let leftEdgeConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
//right edge
let rightEdgeConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
// bottom edge
let topEdgeConstraint  = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.topMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)
// add all constraints
button.addConstraints([leftEdgeConstraint,rightEdgeConstraint,topEdgeConstraint])}
```

Comment: And here am not using any story board reference am only creating from class itself by programmtically.

Comment: Save yourself the pain and use SnapKit: https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit

Comment: @ekscrypto i appreciate your help but i want in pure auto layout not any third party

Comment: @mag_zbc Thanks for your time. I tried it in viewdidload even viewwillappear but none of them are working. Any other idea?

Comment: Never call `addConstraints`. Call `activate` or `isActive = true`.

Comment: @Deepkumar replace this line button.addConstraints([leftEdgeConstraint,rightEdgeConstraint,topEdgeConstraint])} with self.view.addConstraints([leftEdgeConstraint,rightEdgeConstraint,topEdgeConstraint])} and your problem will solve

Comment: Also, don't make these calls in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, because it can be called many times. You were better off doing it in `viewDidLoad` because it is called only once.

Comment: And use anchor notation. No one uses `NSLayoutConstraint(item:` any more.

Answer (score 1):

First constraints should be added to `self.view`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let button = UIButton(type: .system)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button.setTitle("mytitle", for: .normal)

    button.setTitleColor(.green, for: .normal)

    button.backgroundColor = .black

    self.view.addSubview(button)

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),

        button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),

        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,constant:20)

   ])
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You are adding the constraints to the view not button. And one more thing is that the self.view already with in the view hierarchy which comes inside the view controller i think u got my point.

Comment: constraints between a parent view and it's subview should be added to the parant

Comment: yes but when those views are custom views please go through the question once again..

Comment: please test it first and see

Comment: call method **updateTheChanges** inside **viewDidLoad**

Comment: I test it no luck Thanks.

Comment: set title like this **button.setTitle("title", for: .normal)**

Comment: @Deepkumar did all what i said in answer ?? this should 100% work

Comment: My question is about nslayoutconstraint and by using nslayoutconstraint not with anchor which you used.

Comment: Did This by using anchors

Comment: yes , anchor is new version instead of adding constraints like what you did

Answer (score 0):

You are adding constraints to the button but you should add them to `self.view`. [You can check that Gist for full answer.](https://gist.github.com/onurgenes/4bc63cd9e824f93c7f3aefe70eebcd1d)

Change

```
button.addConstraints([...])
```

to

```
view.addConstraints([...])
```

Also for changing the `titleLabel` and `titleColor` you should use

```
button.setTitle("dasdasdas", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
```

Comment: No luck bro ... Same crash And here what enviorment am using   Xcode 9.4.1 ios version : 11.2

Comment: Edited answer. Please check. @Deepkumar

Comment: Bro why to add constraint to view.. And even if i change its not working

Comment: Added a link to the gist. Check gist for full implementation. AutoLayout is working like that. @Deepkumar

Comment: can u try to change rightEdgeConstraint constant to 30. Its not working if i change constant of rightedgeconstraint.

Comment: You should give -30 to right edge. Because plus goes to the right side. @Deepkumar

Comment: Have one question.. Added constraints to button and why to view am not getting?

Comment: I don't know the details but in AutoLayout you always set the constraints for praent view. Not the view itself. Also you can use anchoring methods. With anchoring, you can set Anchors for the view itself.